# Installing an SSD to a laptop w/o the nest

Tags: ssd

I have an ASUS FX505-DT. It had an HDD, it was in a box or something and I took both of them out. Now I want to install an SSD but I don't have that box with me. I couldn't find a place to buy it online, do I need that to install the SSD?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this box business, but if you want to install an SSD on your laptop, first you must determine if your PC has a SATA or M.2 connector, because the form factor and connection to the motherboard are entirely different. How old is this PC? The only ASUS FX505-DT I found (https://www.amazon.in/FX505DT-Graphics-5-3550H-Windows-FX505DT-AL106T/dp/B07RTYFS9S) already comes with an M.2 SSD out of the, well, box...

Comment: @Didier I know it has an SSD, I want to install an SSD where the HDD was. But I don't have the thing where you put the HDD in.

Comment: Every part that laptop has, is there because it’s required for safe, stable and reliable operation of the device. On most Asus laptops I believe the box that you are talking about is/are thin metal strip(s) on either side that secure the standard 2.5” HDD/SSD to the rest of the components. Assuming you want to install a standard 2.5" SSD, to be conservative, you should contact the Asus Service center in your region whenever you get a chance in future and try to get your SSD fitted thru them using the required attachments that they are likely to have with them.

Comment: I think I'm gonna use a double sided tape 'till I get my hands on the bracket.